# map data to make a Web application for displaying location of my customers

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, web-applications, maps

I want to create a Web application in which I need a map data of certain area and would like to show the details or location of my customers.

I have seen the Google maps api,  but I was searching if I could get something privately for my web application.

Please reply. Thanks.in advance

Comment: Probably recommended you use a map API like Google Maps for this since it will be kept up to date and is much easier to use than making your own map application

Comment: But Sam Hood,  can Yu please tell me about maps api,  I just want to.know if  the maps provided by.maps api will show other markers ( shops,petrol bunks,aims etc) or it will be privately showing my data.

Comment: the maps are very configurable, you can choose to show public data if you wish, but by default it shows just a map and allows you to do whatever you wish.

Start here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 0):

You can add [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) to your map. Markers are designed to be interactive with 'click' events. You can add an event listener to bring up an info window displaying custom information. These marker will only show what you specify. They will not show other marker ( shops,petrol bunks,aims etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the Places API from Google in order to show various places on the Google Maps and also the detailed description about that Places.

Here is the detailed description for the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android/).

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) that may help you in your implementation.